# Android Room map sub select result to a non column parameter

Tags: sqlite, android-room, android-livedata

I have

```
@Entity
public class Tag {
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
private long id;
@ColumnInfo(name = "name")
private String name;
@Ignore
private int totalRecords;
}
```

and

```
@Query("SELECT *) FROM Tags ORDER BY importance DESC, name ASC")
LiveData<List<Tag>> getAll();
```

I wanted to select count of tags from anther table and map it to 'totalRecords'
So, my query became

```
@Query("SELECT *, (SELECT count(id) from RecordingAndTags where tagId=t.id) as totalRecords FROM Tags t ORDER BY importance DESC, name ASC")
LiveData<List<Tag>> getAll();
```

As you might have guessed it failed with

```
The query returns some columns [totalRecords] which are not use by com.myapp.entities.Tag. You can use @ColumnInfo annotation on the fields to specify the mapping.
```

So I have modified my 'totalRecords' as

```
@ColumnInfo(name = "totalRecords")
@Ignore
private int totalRecords;
```

Unfortunately it too didn't work and failed with same warning.

Am I missing something? Can't I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be no longer an issue with `1.1.0-beta2`